# database not inserting using PDO prepared statements

Tags: database, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a paypal form which is submitted and working, this is part of the ipn, which means I can not see the error reporting on page which means I am a little blind on what is the issue.

Everything looks fine I think.

Here is the code:

```
$newcustom = rtrim($_POST['custom'], ',');

    $buyingarray = explode('~', $newcustom);

    $name           = $buyingarray[1];
    $phone          = $buyingarray[2];
    $email          = $buyingarray[3];
    $comments       = $buyingarray[4];
    $date           = $buyingarray[5];
    $time           = explode(",",$tt[6]);
    $person         = explode(",",$tt[7]);      
    $orderID        = $tt[0];
    $booking_date   = strtotime($date);

    $nowitsdate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime("now"));

    $addreservation = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations (id, dateCreated, name, email, phone, comments, status, eventID, voucherCode, voucherplace, OrderID) VALUES ('', :dateCreated, :name, :email, :phone, :comments, 1, NULL, '', 'PayPal Purchase', :OrderID)");

    $addreservation->execute(array(':dateCreated' => $nowitsdate,':name' => $name,':email' => $email,':phone' => $phone,':comments' => $comments,':OrderID' => $orderID));

    $addreservation_num = $addreservation->rowCount();

    if($addreservation_num == 0){ $inserterror = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO testipn (id, testing, testing2) VALUES ('','Input into reservations died','')"); exit();}
```

Now I know that everything is ok with the details coming in as I have input each of the variables into the testipn row which is telling me if an error occurred when the ipn is being used.

As far as I can see everything looks fine yet it still is not finding the problem.

Now the only thing I can think it can be is the NULL within the eventID, maybe that is causing an issue?

If a ID is not present which it wont be within this table, then it needs to be NULL.

The rows effected is 0 which means my error row in the database says: Input into reservations died

Thanks for any input into finding a solution :)

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for a link which basically says everything I already know. The server it is on, has no error reporting being sent live or stored. I have tried to access them already

Comment: Well, if you've done all those things, then maybe you should show us your debug statements, and what values you're getting from them.  Remember, you're there and we're here, and you have this all set up and we don't.